# scaling background image with js animate - got shaking image

Tags: javascript, css, jquery-animate, shake

I have DIV container with background image in it.

When I animate it with JS animate scale - I got shaking effect. How to make it smooth?

```js
$('body').on('click', '#container', function() {
  $("#container").animate({
   "background-size": 1000 + "px"
  }, 4000);
});
```

```css
#container {
  width: 500px;
  height: 300px;
  margin-top: 100px;
  margin-left: 100px;
  background-color: #eeeeee;
  background-image: url("https://real-e-expo.com/img/609/m5d2c42466d2e9.jpg");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container"></div>
```

Here is JSFiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/rn6kwup0/

Answer (score 0):

Something like this might work. It uses css3 transforms to scale things smoothly:

https://jsfiddle.net/21j3hbae/

```
    .container {
        width: 500px;
        height: 300px;
        margin-top: 100px;
        margin-left: 100px;
        background-color: #eeeeee;


    }

    .container .inner-image {
      width: inherit;
      height: inherit;
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-position: center;
      background-image: url("https://real-e-expo.com/img/609/m5d2c42466d2e9.jpg");
      transform: scale(0.5);
      transition: all 8s ease;
      background-size: 100% auto;
    }

    .container.animate .inner-image {
      transform: scale(2);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The shaking is a result of no hardware acceleration being used in repaint. Whenever animating, it is important to pick certain properties to animate to improve this performance. Animating `transform` is a better choice than `background-size`.

To achieve the change from smaller to larger I changed the jQuery `animate()` function to simply a `css()` change of transforming the scale. The value inside the `scale()` function is the new size. In this example `2` is equal to 200% of the original size.

```
$("#container").css({
  "transform": "scale(2)"
});
```

The added `transition` property in the CSS controls the duration and any easing on the change. You can place this approach inside a div with `overflow: hidden` to achieve the background-image effect.

```js
$('body').on('click', '#container', function() {
  // use transform instead of animating background-size
  $("#container").css({
    "transform": "scale(2)"
  });
});
```

```css
#container {
  width: 500px;
  height: 300px;
  margin-top: 100px;
  margin-left: 100px;
  background-color: #eeeeee;
  background-image: url("https://real-e-expo.com/img/609/m5d2c42466d2e9.jpg");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  /* control the transition speed here, the second value is duration */
  transition: all 3s ease;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container"></div>
```

Comment: I think he wants to maintain the gray background

Answer (score 0):

Set the background-size for initial state as well, add the easing for animation. This is what I achieved.

```js
   $('body').on('click', '#container', function() {

        $("#container").animate({
            "background-size": 100 + "%"
        }, {duration: 9000,
      easing: "linear"});


    });
```

```css
    #container {
        width: 500px;
        height: 300px;
        margin-top: 100px;
        margin-left: 100px;
        background-color: #eeeeee;
        background-image: url("https://real-e-expo.com/img/609/m5d2c42466d2e9.jpg");
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-position: center;

        background-size: 10%;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container"></div>
```